# VS2010, C++, gSOAP: cannot build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gsoap

I am building a solution which connects to S3. I use gSoap++ generated files. 
But receive an error:

```
soapClientLib.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xlocnum(133): error C2129: static function 'void soap_serializeheader(soap *)' declared but not defined
1>          c:\gsoap-2.8\gsoap\stdsoap2.h(2228) : see declaration of 'soap_serializeheader'
```

I have checked  file which I have included to my solution soapC.cpp, this method exists:

```
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_serializeheader(struct soap *soap)
{
    if (soap->header)
        soap_serialize_SOAP_ENV__Header(soap, soap->header);
}
```

How to fix this error?
Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: do you have your includes done well? Particularly, have you #included *.nsmap file?

Answer (score 0):

Remove "soapClientLib.cpp" from your project.